# Reference: A nowhere vanishing section of a vector bundle is locally split

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Well-known fact:

> If $(A, \mathfrak{m})$ is a local Noetherian ring, $E$ is a finitely generated free $A$-module, and $e\in E$ is an element not contained in $\mathfrak{m}E$, then $E/eA$ is also a free $A$-module.

Significantly, there  is no assumption that $A$ is reduced or otherwise "nice" in any way other than being local and Noetherian.

While I do know how to prove this statement, I am having an embarrassingly difficult time tracking down an existing reference (preferably, but not necessarily, in a standard text on commutative algebra or similar). Can anyone help?

Comment: Bourbaki *Commutative Algebra* II, §3, Proposition 6.

Comment: If this is for a paper and you wish to do more than leave it to the reader (despite it being well-known) then a 1-sentence proof may be more helpful then a literature reference (e.g., "a residually nonzero element extends to a residual basis, which in turn lifts to an $A$-basis since an endomorphism of $A^n$ that reduces to an isomorphism is an isomorphism due to  locality").  Or Theorem 2.3 in "Commutative Ring Theory" by H. Matsumura.

Comment: @user52824: Thanks for the reference. The reference itself is for my thesis, but I'm also hoping to turn it into a paper, in which the statement will be left to the reader (if I even state it explicitly).